# Programming with Reference Class

Tags: r, reference-class

1. How to define several polymorph constructors and functions like

   ```
   function Add( x, y : Integer ) : Integer;
   begin
       Add := x + y
   end;

   function Add( s, t : String ) : String;
   begin
       Add := Concat( s, t )
   end;

   begin
       Writeln(Add(1, 2));
       Writeln(Add('Hello, ', 'World!'));
   end.
   ```

Can I do this only by case decission like

```
A<-setRefClass(Class = "A"
              ,fields = list(var1="character")
              ,methods = list(setFields=A.setFields
                             ,initialize=function(var1) {
                                if(isClass(var1,"B"))
                                   .self$var1<-as.character(var1$getFields("var1"))                                  
                                else{
                                  .self$var1<-as.character(var1)
                                }
                                .self
                              })
)
```

1. How to combine functional programming with objectorientated prgramming. So if I would call the functions getFields(vecB), where vecB is a vector or list of objects B. The return should be the values of each object?

   ```
    B.getFields<-function(...,values){ 
      vars<-mget(names(.refClassDef@fieldClasses), envir = attr(.self, ".xData"))
      if(missing(values)) 
        return(vars)
      if(length(vars)==1)
        return(vars[[1]])
     return(vars[names(vars) %in% values])
     }

        B<-setRefClass(Class = "B"
                  ,fields = list(var1 = "character")
                    )
   ```
2. How to debug e.g. the function initialize from class A? I tried

   ```
   A$trace("initialize")
   a<-A$new("ABC")
   initial<-a$initialize
   trace(initial,browser,where=A)
   ```

   but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use S4 generics and methods for polymorphism

   ```
   setGeneric("Add", function(x, y) standardGeneric("Add"))
   setMethod(Add, c("numeric", "numeric"), function(x, y) x + y)
   setMethod(Add, c("character", "character"), function(x, y) paste0(x, y))
   ```

   so

   ```
   > Add(1, 2)
   [1] 3
   > Add("hello ", "world")
   [1] "hello world"
   > Add("hello ", 2)
   Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
     unable to find an inherited method for function 'Add' for signature '"character", "numeric"'
   ```

   One idea to use this generic in a reference class is

   ```
   A <- setRefClass("A",
       fields=list(x="ANY"),
       methods=list(
         getX=function() {
             .self$x
         }, setX=function(x) {
             .self$x <- x
             .self
         }, addX=function(y) {
             setX(Add(getX(), y))
         }, show=function() {
             cat("class:", class(.self), "\nx:", getX(), "\n")
         }))
   ```

   with appropriate dispatch for functional program style:

   ```
   setMethod(Add, c("A", "ANY"), function(x, y) x$addX(y))
   setMethod(Add, c("A", "A"), function(x, y) x$addX(y$getX()))
   ```

   (maybe for functional programming it makes more sense to implement `$addX()` as `A(.self, x=Add(x$getX(), y))`, i.e., creating a clone of x?) to allow for

   ```
   > Add(A(x=1), A(x=2))
   class: A 
   x: 3 
   > Add(A(x="hello "), "world")
   class: A 
   x: hello world 
   > A(x=2)$addX(3)
   class: A 
   x: 5
   ```

   though not `A(x=1)$addX(A(x=2))`
2. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713847/return-a-list-of-fields-of-a-reference-class/18716850#18716850) for one approach to returning field values:

   ```
   B = setRefClass("B", fields=c(var1="list", var2="character"),
       methods=list(getFields=function(values) {
           flds = names(getRefClass()$fields())
           if (!missing(values))
               flds = flds[flds %in% values]
           result = setNames(vector("list", length(flds)), flds)
           for (fld in flds)
               result[[fld]] = .self[[fld]]
           result
       }))
   ```

   One way to invoke in a functional way requires a separate implementation, e.g.,

   ```
   setGeneric("getFields", function(x, ...) standardGeneric("getFields"))
   setMethod(getFields, "B", function(x, ...) x$getFields(...))
   setMethod(getFields, "list", function(x, ...) lapply(x, getFields, ...))
   ```
3. Your class A example is incomplete.

   ```
   A <- setRefClass("A", methods=list(initialize=function(...) {
       message("hello A")
       callSuper(...)
   }))
   ```

   and then

   ```
   > A$trace("initialize", browser)
   Tracing reference method "initialize" for class "A"
   [1] "initialize"
   > A()
   Tracing .Object$initialize(...) on entry 
   Called from: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
   Browse[1]> n
   debug: {
       message("hello A")
       callSuper(...)
   }
   Browse[2]> n
   debug: message("hello A")
   Browse[2]>
   ```

Comment: 1) But how to combine the Generic method with Reference Classes, is it allowd to use the function Add as a memberfunction of class B? 2) How extend `getFields` for a functional programming paradigm, I mean, to use the function as a Refernce Class function. So if I would call the function via getFields(vecB,"var1"), where vecB is a vector of objects of class B ,it should return var1 from each object. So that it works in the same way like all the other functions in R.

Comment: @Heiko I added some ideas; hope it helps.

Comment: If its legal to do so, then it helps, I had also something like that in mind but I am to new to decide if my thoughts has validity. But your first approach is readed like a endless loop `setMethod(Add, c("A", "ANY"), function(x, y) x$addX(y))` but I do not tested till now, so I think I do not understand it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a previous discussion on polymorphisms in R: [What are the suggested practices for function polymorphism in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932808/what-are-the-suggested-practices-for-function-polymorphism-in-r)

The way to concatenate a string is with paste.

```
paste("Hello, ","world",sep="")
```

Comment: Or `paste0` if you get tired of writing out `sep=""` each time.